# google analytics api php, how to access total sessions for all landing pages that start with a certain url

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

i want to access the total number of sessions for landing pages that start with the url "/biz".

Here are the dimensions and metrics I am using:

```
    $dimensions = "ga:landingpagePath";
    $metrics = "ga:sessions";
    $filters = "ga:landingpagePath=~^/biz"; 
    $sort = "-ga:sessions";
```

But this prints out the individual pages and sessions for each.  I want all of these sessions added up.  And I cant write a program to do it myself because there are just too many of them and they exceed the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the dimension ga:landingPagePath if you want to get the aggregated value. If you have to set dimensions to a non-blank value use something with just one row expecting like ga:hostname.